# How to implement NSLog to trace CGPoint coordinates

Tags: objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor, nslog

I'm trying  to find a simple way to call a NSLog to trace myPoint coordinates.
I figured out that I can define a macro like this:

```
#define NSLogPoint(__P__) NSLog(@"%s x:%f , y:%f", #__P__, __P__.x, __P__.y)
```

Using # before the parameter it will trace it as is,
so I could have:

```
 CGPoint myPoint = CGPointMake(3,4);
 NSLogPoint(myPoint);
```

that will trace:

```
myPoint x:3.000000 , y:4.000000
```

is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have no decimal places:

```
#define NSLogPoint(__P__) NSLog(@"%s x:%.0f , y:%.0f", #__P__, __P__.x, __P__.y)
```

To have two decimal places:

```
#define NSLogPoint(__P__) NSLog(@"%s x:%.2f , y:%.2f", #__P__, __P__.x, __P__.y)
```